# Fetch a single commit from remote

Tags: git

There is a commit in the remote repo that I do not have in my local history. It was made before my most recent commit. How do I get this into my local copy?

Basically, how do I handle the fact that the commits are out of order in the history?

I don't think `git fetch` alone will do the job.

Conceptually this isn't hard - it is all happening on a single branch - but this particular project is unlike anything else I've used with respect to remotes, so I am unsure about how to get only the changes that have occurred there and nothing else.

To illustrate this, the history is as follows:

[image: history]

Comment: Can you give a more specific example? Show an example commit history for both your local and the remote repos. In particular, are you talking about commits on the same branch in each repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commits *are* the history, so they cannot be "out of order in the history" as that means "the history is not in the order of the history", which is obviously impossible. :-)  But you're right that `git fetch` alone won't do the trick.  What you need is `git fetch`, and then a second Git command.

#### Necessary background

More precisely, each commit "points to" its parent commit or, for merge commits, its parents (plural).  That is, each commit is named by its big ugly hash ID—these are the "true names" of commits and are how Git actually retrieves them from the commit database—and each commit contains, as part of itself, the ID(s) of its parent commit(s).

To get Git started with viewing or using commits, Git needs the ID of a *tip* commit of a branch.  Git stores these in the branch names, so we say that `master` *points to* a specific commit, which then points back to its parent, which points to its parent in turn, and so on:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
```

This is a drawing of a repository with just three commits.  Instead of their real names, I use one-letter names (which limits me to just 26 commits, but I'm not going to draw even that many).  Note how all the internal arrows point backwards: the name `master` finds commit `C` for us, and then `C` lets us find `B` because `C` store's `B`'s hash ID.  Likewise, `B` stores `A`'s ID.  Because `A` is the *first* commit ever made, it can't point back to a previous commit; we call this a *root commit*.  (All repositories have at least one, and often only one—it's a little tricky to make more than one–root commit.  In any case, root commits are where this backwards-chain-following always stops.)

The fact that all the internal arrows are backwards is usually not interesting, so it's easier to draw these without those arrows:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

To add a *new* commit `D` to this branch, Git first writes out the new commit with the current branch-tip commit ID as its parent, then changes the ID stored with the name `master` to the *new* commit's ID:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

and thus we add a commit to a branch.  This is how you add commits to your own branches, including your own `master` branch.

But—here's the problem—Git is *distributed*, so while you have *your* `master` branch, other users have *their* `master` branches.  They add a new commit `E` to *their* master:

```
A--B--C--E   <-- master   # in THEIR repository
```

Their `E` points back to the commit `C` that you both share.  The "real name" of commit `C` is one of those big ugly hash IDs and is *the same* in *every* repository that has that commit.<sup>1</sup>  Every commit ever made gets its own unique hash ID, so your new commit `D` has a different ID from their new commit `E`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This seemingly magical property is what makes Git work as a *distributed* version control system.

---

#### What `git fetch` does

When you `git fetch` from someone who made their commit `E`, and you have made your own commit `D`, your Git *adds* their commit (or commits, however many they added) to *your* repository:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
       \
        E    [their commit]
```

Your Git, though, needs a way to *find* their commit `E`: remember, we said above that Git works by having a branch name, or something similar, pointing to the *tip* commit.  *Their* tip commit is this new `E`, so Git uses a *remote-tracking branch* to remember that their—`origin`'s—`master` now does, or did anyway the last time you ran `git fetch`, point to `E`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
       \
        E    <-- origin/master
```

#### How you *combine* this is up to you

It's now *your* job to do something about this branching difference between *your* `master` and *their* `master`, which your Git is remembering for you using the name `origin/master`.

There are basically two things you can do to combine your work and their work: you can *merge*, or you can *rebase*.  (Or, of course, you can refuse to combine things: either throw away your `D` entirely, or just never coöperate with them again. :-) I will assume you are not going to go this route.)

#### Combining by merging

To *merge* your work with theirs, you run `git merge` (or `git merge origin/master`).  Your Git will figure out what you did, by comparing your commit `D` to the *merge base* commit `C`, and then figure out what *they* did, by comparing your commit `E`—which is a bit-for-bit identical copy of their commit, obtained by your `git fetch`—to the merge base `C`.  Your Git will then make its best effort at combining the two, and if all goes well, will commit the result as a *merge commit*, which has *both* your `D` and the shared `E` as its two parents:

```
A--B--C--D--F   <-- master
       \   /
        \ /
         E      <-- origin/master
```

Since this new merge commit incorporates both your work and their work, you can now `git push` your `master` to share your *two* new commits `D` and `F`.  Your new `F` retains their `E` and adds your `D`, so if they add these to their repository, they do not lose anything.  If you successfully `git push` this, they add those two commits and your Git remembers their new `master`:

```
A--B--C--D--F   <-- master, origin/master
       \   /
        \ /
         E
```

You and they are now back in sync.

#### Combining by rebasing

Usually, though, it's better to *rebase* your work.  What `git rebase` does is *copy* commits.  Your existing `D` is OK, but has one problem: it's based on `C`.  What Git can do for you is to *copy* `D` to a new and improved commit `D'` that is *like* `D` but:

1. is based on `E` (starts with their changes and has the shared `E` as its parent), and
2. has a new, different hash ID.

If you do this successfully, you have your Git just abandon the old `D` (though it's remembered for at least 30 days by default if you decide you want it back), and your graph now looks like this:

```
        D     [abandoned]
       /
A--B--C   D'  <-- master
       \ /
        E     <-- origin/master
```

You now have a commit `D'` that merely *adds on* to their work, so you can `git push` the result.  Once you do, *their* master will point to your `D'`.  We can now forget the original `D` entirely and draw the graph like this:

```
A--B--C--E--D'  <-- master, origin/master
```

and your and their repositories are in sync.

#### Git pull (but don't use it)

All `git pull` does is run `git fetch` for you, and then run a second Git command.  Usually that's `git merge`, but you can tell it to run `git rebase` instead as its second command.

This is supposed to be more convenient than running the two commands.  And it is—but there are some problems, admittedly all minor:

- The default is wrong: `git rebase` is usually better.
- If things go wrong—they always do, eventually—you'll know what to look for if you do both commands separately.  If you don't *know* that `git pull` has run `git merge`, and it goes wrong, how do you know to look for help about `git merge`?
- Last, in complicated setups or with a lot of commits, sometimes merge is better and sometimes rebase is better.  The way to *decide which to use* is to obtain their commits, then *look*, and only *then* decide.  With `git pull` you have to decide before you look: it's like driving across the drawbridge without first checking to see if it's open.

#### When not to rebase

Note that your `D'` is now *published* and *shared* and it's no longer a good idea to copy it and throw away `D'`.  The same holds if you merge and push: your `D` and `F` will be published and shared, and it will be bad to try to rebase them, as anyone who picked them up will retain them.  Remember, Git is built around the idea of *always adding new commits*, not so much discarding old ones.  It's much easier to *add* to a repository: Git does all of it automatically.  It's not hard to discard commits from *your* repository, but once they are published and many people have them in many repositories, you must get *all* those other people to do the *same* discard action.

Comment: This was resolved by another contributor, but I'm marking this as the answer for general reference.

Answer (score 2):

`git pull` will sort this out.  It doesn't *really* matter what order the commit was done in; Git will attempt to merge it in cleanly, then defer to you if there are conflicts which can't be simply rectified.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should always create a new branch before making commits. This is especially true when you contribute to a team project. Doing so will make situations like this easier to manage because you can always pull to your local `master` branch to get the most recent contributions from others without worrying about conflicts with your own work. Then you only merge whenever you are ready to deal with any possible conflicts.

Now to deal with your current situation, you should be able to `git fetch` and/or `git pull` without any problems. The difference is that `git fetch` will only update the commits on the remote tracking branch. `git pull` will also merge the changes into your current branch. As long as the other changes do not create any conflicts, the merge will cleanly apply and you will not know any difference regarding the order of the changes. If there are conflicts, then you will have to resolve them manually before finalizing the merge commit.

Comment: There are some development flows which *don't* require you make a branch.  Sure, it defeats some purpose out of Git, but you also don't have to deal with messy merge branches.

Comment: @Makoto You still have to deal with merges since you have to fetch and merge the remote tracking branch.

Comment: Note that I said "merge branches", not *merges*.  You will *inevitably* merge.   [This article](http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/branchless-development) goes into more detail on the matter than I will, but stating "always" is an anomaly.  I'd appreciate it if it weren't in the answer.